# Error 500 on page reload after move to another domain // Permission problem?

Tags: error, http-error-500, domain

I am trying to move a magento plateform from a domain to another (in a sub folder).
To do that, i referred to this tutorial:
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-move-your-website-from-one-domain-to-another.html

I think i succeed to change url modifications and database connexions because the first time i try to go the le site, the homepage worked well.

Unfortunately, then i notice when i reload this homepage i get an 500 error: **Internal Server Error**...

First i thought about a permission error. So i double checked the permission and i tried the magento-cleanup.php script:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

I think it reset well file permissions because just after this script finished, i was able to go to the home again.
But on reload the same error come back and i have to redo the process (error > script > work > reload > error).

For information, i have configure memory_limit to 128M.

Could it be a miss configuration in the database which break the permissions?

Any advice will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a guess, but it's most likely not a problem with the database. You might try these to find out what causes this error:

### Clear cache from Magento panel

Go to System > Cache Management and clear all caches. Or even better disable them for the time of debugging. This will make sure, that all cache is cleared.

### Check RewriteBase in .htaccess

Make sure that RewriteBase in your .htaccess file matches site's new location. You may also want to check if it is a rewrite problem. If **yourdomain.com/magento/some-category/some-product.html** doesn't work try **yourdomain.com/magento/index.php/some-category/some-product.html**. You might even try turning off pretty urls in rewrites in System > Configuration > Web > Search Engines Optimisation

### Check Apache/PHP logs

Check server logs for anything that might cause the error.

### Check Magento logs

They are located in var/log folder of your Magento root. If you can't find any please check if they are enabled in System > Configuration > Developer > Log settings.

Comment: Thank you Maciek for your answer.

Unfortunatly because of the error, i can't access to the back office.

I read the problem could come from the cache folder: the server change the permission on the folder when it regenerate the files. No solution was find.

Comment: Did you try clearing and disabling cache? If you have SSH access to the server, you can do it using magerun - https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#clean-magento-cache

Comment: Maciek, after a test of different solutions, i finaly solved these issue by changing my hosting solution which is was a little under scale to use with magento. Thank you for your help.